# How to customize pagination toolbar in extjs 4

Tags: javascript, pagination, extjs4

i have a dataview and i am showing some images inside it. Now i am doing pagination for the dataview. I dont need the default paging bar using extjs. What i need is a customised one. That is there will be an icon for showing previos page on the left side of dataview and an icon indicating next page on the right page in between two icons i have to show the page count like "1,2,3,4,5".
Is it possible to customize the default paging bar in this way?

```
                        {
                            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                            store: store,  
                            dock: 'bottom',
                            displayInfo: false,
                            border:0
                        }
```

[image]

Comment: you mean the `show 15` dropdown for changing the paging size or what exactly do you want?

Comment: @Jandalf No i want to show the page count "1,2,3,4,5"

Comment: It would probably be easiest to just make your own toolbar.